# Can't move/resize windows with Logitech wireless mouse connected (Precise)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, mouse, logitech

On 12.04 Precise, when I connect a Logitech wireless mouse (M305), I'm no longer able to drag windows around via their title bar or resize them. Also, the selection highlight doesn't seem to track the cursor properly and I'm unable to click on some things. The cursor moves around smoothly and is completely responsive - I'm just very limited in click/drag options.

Is there an alternate driver besides the built-in HID driver that might fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by disabling then re-enabling Smart Move in the Logitech mouse settings

Comment: Could you please provide more information about enabling disabling Smart Move.